# Changing ttl for networkaddress.cache.ttl not working

Tags: java, java-8, tomcat8.5

I am trying to set X seconds on networkaddress cache TTL in *java.security* file, but seems like changes are not affecting the cache. My request still go to the older machine.

I have hosted my application as WAR in Tomcat.

Does Tomcat also has to do anything with DNS caching.
My only solution for now looks like to restart the Tomcat everytime my DNS points to a new machine.

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the DNS cache time with the `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl` JVM parameter. To set a JVM parameter on your Tomcat instance, add a `setenv.sh` file to the `/bin` directory of your Tomcat installation and add a line like:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=2"
```

Which will give you a DNS cache time of 2 seconds.

If you are on Windows you will need to modify the above to be a valid `.bat` file, but the JVM parameter is the same.